# Create hash of instance methods references

Tags: ruby

I have a class that can parse different types of messages and what I want to do is to create a hash that will use the msg type id as the keys and different instance methods as the values.

Something like this:

```
class Parser
    def initialize(msg_id)
        @my_methods = {1 => method_1, 2 => method_2, 3 => method_3}
        @my_methods[msg_id]()

    end

    def method_1
    end

    def method_2
    end

    def method_3
    end end
```

I know it's possible, but I am not sure how to do it. I tried using the `self.method(:method_1)` as a value but I got an error saying that `method_1` is not defined.

Thank you

Comment: The `self.method(:method_1)` syntax should have worked just fine, but, only if `self` really has a `method_1` method, defined when the `method` method is called. For example, you can do that inside the `initialize` method, since that is also an instance method and `self` is an instance of your Parser class, but if you tried doing it in a class method, it's not going to work, since `method_1` is not also a class method.

Answer (score 1):

While provided answer would work fine, there are few "minor" issues with it:

1. If there'd be tons of methods, hardcoding such hash would take time, and since it is not dynamic (because you have to update the hash manually each time new method is added to the class body) it is very error prone.
2. Even though you are within the class, and technically have access to all methods defined with any visibility scope with implicit receiver (including `private` and `protected`), it is still a good practice to *only rely on public interface*, thus, I'd recommend to use [Object#`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send).

---

So here is what I would suggest (despite the fact I do not see how the idea of having such map would work in real life):

```
class Parser
  def initialize(msg_id)
    # generate a dynamic hash with keys starting with 1
    # and ending with the size of the methods count
    methods_map = Hash[(1..instance_methods.size).zip(instance_methods)]

    # Use public_send to ensure, only public methods are accessed
    public_send(methods_map[msg_id])
  end

  # create a method, which holds a list of all instance methods defined in the class
  def instance_methods
    self.class.instance_methods(false)
  end
end
```

After a quick thought I refactored it a bit, so that we hide the implementation of the mapping to `private` methods:

```
class Parser
  def initialize(msg_id)
    public_send(methods_map[msg_id])
  end

  # methods omitted

  private

  def methods_map # not methods_hash, because what we do is mapping
    Hash[(1..instance_methods.size).zip(instance_methods)]
    # or
    # Hash[instance_methods.each.with_index(1).map(&:reverse)]
  end

  def instance_methods
    self.class.instance_methods(false)
  end
end
```

Comment: at the moment of writing `While provided answer` there was only one answer by **AJ Gregory** :)

Comment: What about `def methods_map; Hash[methods(false).each.with_index(1).map (&:reverse)]` (and removing your instance method `instance_methods`)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland thx, actually also though about `methods(false)` sometime after giving this answer, but did not edit. Edited now!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just realized, that `methods` won't work at all, since it returns a list of singleton_methods, when `false` passed as an argument..

Comment: It should be `methods(false)`, which is equivalent to `self.class.instance_methods(false)`. N'est-ce pas?

Comment: @CarySwoveland `class Foo; def bar; end end` and `Foo.instance_methods(false) == Foo.new.methods(false)` => `false`. Because `methods(false)` returns a list of object's singleton methods. `Foo.instance_methods(false)` => `[:bar]` and `Foo.new.methods(false)` => `[]`. And: `baz = Foo.new; def baz.qux;end`, `baz.methods(false)` => `[:qux]`

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that, but good to know. So let's make that `Hash[self.class.instance_methods(false).each.with_index(1).map(&:reverse)]`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible changes to fix your code are like this:

```
class Parser
  def initialize(msg_id)
    @my_methods = { 1 => method(:method_1), 2 => method(:method_2), 3 => method(:method_3) }
    @my_methods[msg_id].()
  end

  def method_1; end
  def method_2; end
  def method_3; end
end
```

I.e. use the [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method to get a [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) object, and use the [`Method#call`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-call) method to execute it.

However, there are a few improvements we could make. For one, your [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) associates [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html)s with values. But there is a better data structure which already does that: an [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html). (Note: if your message IDs are not assigned sequentially, then a `Hash` is probably the right choice, but from the looks of your example, they are just `Integer`s counting up from `1`.)

And secondly, hardcoding the methods inside the `Parser#initialize` method is probably not a good idea. There should be a declarative description of the protocol, i.e. the message IDs and their corresponding method names somewhere.

```
class Parser
  # this will make your message IDs start at 0, though
  PROTOCOL_MAPPING = [:method_1, :method_2, :method_3].freeze

  def initialize(msg_id)
    @my_methods = PROTOCOL_MAPPING.map(&method(:method))
    @my_methods[msg_id].()
  end

  def method_1; end
  def method_2; end
  def method_3; end
end
```

Another possibility would be something like this:

```
class Parser
  PROTOCOL_MAPPING = []

  private_class_method def self.parser(name)
    PROTOCOL_MAPPING << name
  end

  def initialize(msg_id)
    @my_methods = PROTOCOL_MAPPING.map(&method(:method))
    @my_methods[msg_id].()
  end

  parser def method_1; end
  parser def method_2; end
  parser def method_3; end
end
```

Or maybe this:

```
class Parser
  PROTOCOL_MAPPING = {}

  private_class_method def self.parser(msg_id, name)
    PROTOCOL_MAPPING[msg_id] = name
  end

  def initialize(msg_id)
    @my_methods = PROTOCOL_MAPPING.map {|msg_id, name| [msg_id, method(name)] }.to_h.freeze
    @my_methods[msg_id].()
  end

  parser 1, def method_1; end
  parser 2, def method_2; end
  parser 3, def method_3; end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is `send`.

Note that the values in your hash need to be symbols to be passed to `send`.

```
class Parser
    def initialize(msg_id)
        @my_methods = {1 => :method_1, 2 => :method_2, 3 => :method_3}
        send(@my_methods[msg_id])
    end

    def method_1
    end

    def method_2
    end

    def method_3
    end
end
```

[Documentation here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send)

Comment: Send will work fine, but the `method(:method_1)` option should also have worked, so something else may be going on.